# Get currently logged user friends list - JsSDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently my fb-app require below permission:

- public_profile
- user_friends
- read_friendlists

I'm using some facebook sdk provided function to get user data.

```
var getUserData = function (id, url, callback, params) {
    if (params !== undefined){
        FB.api(id + '/' + url, params,
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    callback(response);
                } else {
                    console.log("#Error");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
    } else {
        FB.api(id + '/' + url,
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    callback(response);
                } else {
                    console.log("#Error");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
getUserData("/me", "friends", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}, {fields: 'name,id,location,birthday'});
```

In response i get only users who logged early to my application (not currently logged-user friends)
What is correct way to get logged-user freinds using facaebook api ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API v2.0 (which you will be if you created the app after 4/30/2014) then /me/friends will only return friends that are using the app and not all friends.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible using fb api ?

Comment: It is not possible in any way. You might want to look at the Taggable and Invitable Friends api's.